# Redirecting processes from multiprocessing to separate wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, multiprocessing

I have four text boxes and up to four processes that I will be starting using the multiprocessing module.  I can get the processes to execute properly, but I would really like to redirect all the output of each process to a different wx.TextCtrl so I can see what is going on throughout the solution process.  I have done this successfully with a single thread and sys.stdout redirection as in

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t515815-wxpython-redirect-the-stdout-to-a-textctrl.html

but a similar idea doesn't work with processes.  Can someone hack me a simple solution for this problem?  I can't imagine I am the only person to have ever run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, in wxPython land you normally want to run processes from a thread. So you communicate from the processes to the thread and from the thread back to wxPython. I would use some kind of naming scheme to associate each potential process with a text control (maybe 1-4?) and pass that back to the thread which will use wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent to tell wx to update.

You might be able to use a simple Python socket server to accomplish this too. Post a message to the server with a header that says which text control it belongs to. In the wx part you could have a wx.Timer check the socket server for new messages and update as appropriate.

Comment: Mike, that's more or less what I ended up having to do.  I got it working without blocking eventually, I'll post it up soon.  Basically, in the process, redirect all output to a pipe that you parse from the thread.  It works fine, though it is a bit of a pain.

Comment: If you do get a working example, I'd like to see it. I keep wanting to write about using multiprocess and wxPython on my blog, but haven't spent the time to figure it out properly.

Comment: Please see my example in my response

Answer (score 1):

For those that are interested, here is a working code snippet that does what my original question asked.  It works a treat.

This code creates a thread that wraps a process.  Within the run() function of the process the stderr and stdout are redirected to a pipe using a redirection class.  Pipes can be pickled which is a pre-requisite to using them within the run() function of the process.

The Thread then just sits and pulls output from the pipe as long as there is output waiting.  The text pulled from the pipe is written to a wx.TextCtrl using the wx.CallAfter function.  Note that this is a non-blocking call, and in fact all the code here is non-blocking which makes for a responsive GUI.  Note the flush() function in the redirection class to redirect stderr as well.

Note: One thing to be cautious of is that if you are trying to read and write with the pipe at too high a throughput, the GUI will lock up.  But as long as you have reasonably slow output, there is no problem

```
import wx
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process
from threading import Thread

class RedirectText2Pipe(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe_inlet):
        self.pipe_inlet = pipe_inlet
    def write(self, string):
        self.pipe_inlet.send(string)
    def flush(self):
        return None

class Run1(Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe_inlet):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe_std = pipe_inlet

    def run(self):
        redir = RedirectText2Pipe(self.pipe_std)
        sys.stdout = redir
        sys.stderr = redir

        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            print i,'Hi'

class RedirectedWorkerThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    def __init__(self, stdout_target):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stdout_target_ = stdout_target

    def run(self):
        """
        In this function, actually run the process and pull any output from the 
        pipes while the process runs
        """
        pipe_outlet, pipe_inlet = Pipe(duplex = False)
        p = Run1(pipe_inlet)
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

        while p.is_alive():
            #Collect all display output from process
            while pipe_outlet.poll():
                wx.CallAfter(self.stdout_target_.WriteText, pipe_outlet.recv())

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)

        self.txt1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.txt2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.txt3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label='Run')
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.AddMany([(self.txt1,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.txt2,1,wx.EXPAND),(self.txt3,1,wx.EXPAND),self.btn])
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnStart(self, event):
        t1 = RedirectedWorkerThread(self.txt1)
        t1.daemon = True
        t1.start()

        t2 = RedirectedWorkerThread(self.txt2)
        t2.daemon = True
        t2.start()

        t3 = RedirectedWorkerThread(self.txt3)
        t3.daemon = True
        t3.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame() 
    frame.Show(True) 
    app.MainLoop()
```